# Modifications of consonants

Tags: phonetics, consonants, assimilation

Could you help me to figure out one thing?

My task is to comment on the **modifications of consonants** by the neighbouring sounds(assimilation,ellision). But there are some words in the task where I don't see any modifications of consonants:

> bright [braɪt]
>   great [ɡreɪt]
>   duty [ˈdjuːtɪ]
>   beauty [ˈbjuːtɪ]

I want to know, is it just me,or the task is incorrect?

Comment: I think the question is meaningless, without further context. All sounds vary to some extent as a function of context, and such variation is usually imperceptible, requiring phonetic measurement. Is your task-giver asking you about *all* consonants, or some specific one? E.g. /t/? In which dialect of English?

Comment: For starts, the /g/ in _great_ is rounded, because it anticipates the /r/. And /dju/ becomes /dʒu/ very fast. Then there's the tap of /t/ in the last two, and the unreleased final /t/ (which could appear as glottal stop) in the first two. You're not restricted to the IPA phonetics; you're sposta **listen** for the differences.

Comment: It seems a little odd to me that the task presents the word in phonetic brackets rather than phonemic slashes. Are you sure that's how it was written in the task?

Comment: Please don't cross-post: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/55119/modifications-of-consonants

Comment: You can, although I think ideally the two questions would get merged so all the help you received here would appear on the other question as well.